# Is there a way to disable keyboard shortcuts in VLC on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

I have a cat that won't stop walking on my keyboard while I'm watching big bang theory, now it has delayed the audio, changed the aspect ratio and I got some Asian language subtitles.

How can I disable keys in VLC doing this? This is on my laptop.

Comment: Just unplug the keyboard !!!

Comment: @RohitGupta its a laptop u goof

Comment: Oscar, have you thought of sharing this priceless information in your post ?  Just earned a down vote from me.

Comment: I really hope you are joking here. This question was resolved for more than two years ago, I don|t think any changes are relevant.

Comment: Oscar,  I actually edited it to add laptop in it, its waiting for peer review.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer

*Not directly*. But you can set everything to the same key **combination**. By doing so, every hotkey will become unset except the last hotkey, which you can set to be something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. your cat won't probably step on this combination at the same time.

#### Demonstration:

[image: VLC key combinations gif]

Comment: cool gif, nice answer :)

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoVonMatterhorn! I've used [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), it's very handy

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer as of 2017

Button **Unset** was added into hotkeys preferences, so you do not need to do magic on unsetting the hotkeys any more, just double-click each line and press **Unset**.

[image]

Comment: The Delete key also works to unset a hotkey.